# How to Change the column width of the tree view in odoo 13?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I tried creating a css file and I tried creating a assets.xml and added the css filepath to the assets with inherit_id 'web.assets_frontend' But and added a class in the tree tag.
But nothing worksout,Any good method to implement here?

assets.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend_aks_workbook" name="AKS workbook" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/alkidhma/aks_workbook/static/css/aks_workbook.css"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

aks_workbook.css

```
.aks_width_class[data-id="work_description"] {
    width: 175px;
}
```

Tree view:-

```
<tree class="aks_width_class">
<field name="work_description"/>
</tree>
```

manifest.py

```
  'css': ['static/css/aks_workbook.css'],
```

Comment: Does the added class get into the page structure (sourcecode inspection)?

Comment: How to check that in the inspection?? btw i've updated the code please have a look into it

Comment: @holydragon im getting a error like ,
"STYLE ERROR"
Style Compilation failed,
Could not get content for "/alkidhma/aks_workbook/static/css/aks_workbook.css" defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'

Comment: Maybe odoo cannot find the file from the path given. Check [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/style-error-on-web-portal-173279).

Comment: @holydragon yes yes, ive double checked the path and thats not the issue, but i didnt tried restarting the odoo service,will it be the cause?